# New a java object with same primary key, Hibernate merge() generate update sql instead of duplicate primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, merge

In java I create a SalaryscaleDelinked object, then call hibernate merge, it save to db successfully.

Then I create a new SalaryscaleDelinked object, assign the same pk but other field is changed, then call hibernate merge, I expect hibernate will throw primary key exception (because it is a new object with same pk), but instead it said

> "onFlushDirty: Detected dirty object com.frw.hdo.SalaryscaleDelinked@1c340517 with id "04425"

and generate a update sql and update the db record with the same primary key.

1. Why will this happen?
2. use what hibernate method or under what situation will cause the above scenario throw duplicate primary key exception?

Answer (score 0):

1- As beloved Vlad Mihalcea puts it,

> Hibernate can auto-detect incoming changes and schedule SQL UPDATES on
> our behalf. This mechanism is called automatic dirty checking.
> this means that hibernate knows that object is your entity and you are calling merge() on it so you are asking hibernate to update your changes onto your own entity.

As with persist method, the merge method is specified by JSR-220 to have certain semantics that you can rely upon (baeldung site):

if the entity is detached, it is copied upon an existing persistent entity;
if the entity is transient, it is copied upon a newly created persistent entity;
this operation cascades for all relations with cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL mapping;
if the entity is persistent, then this method call does not have an effect on it (but the cascading still takes place).
this is the reason you are updating your entity. through the magic of Hibernate dirty checking.

2- if you call save again on that entity, you will receive the error you want.